# How to use array to design a data structure that has O(1) for get, insert, delete

Tags: arrays, data-structures, hashtable

An interview question:How to use array to design a data structure that has O(1) for get, insert, delete?

My thought is to first pick a prime number as the size of the array and to use "mod by the size of array" as a simple hash function. And for each spot in the array we store a linked list to deal with collision.

Is there any better solutions?

Comment: O(1) at best? [Binary search algo.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) Hash tables also work. If you can make a new structure that can achieve O(1) at average or worst, you should become a University prof.

Comment: You are trying to use a data structure in a way that it is not intended to be used. Arrays are intended to be used for quick retrieval/insertion/deletion if the index is already known. This structure is basically already made; a hashtbale. If you are aiming for something ~O(1) then you should look at hashtable implmentations and not try to alter a structure in a way that it's not intended to be used.

Comment: But you can't tell them that if you are asked during an interview

Comment: @sjagr Don't hash tables have (in theory) O(1) average time for get, insert, and delete?

Comment: @EvanBechtol Many hashtables are implemented using arrays, so one legitimate answer would be "make an array-based hash table" (plus details on how you would do that).

Comment: @JLRishe A valid point! I was just wondering why OP is trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @user3692521 I actually think it might be a good idea to tell your interviewer "isn't that just a hashtable?" and get the discussion going from there. They might ask you what you know about hash tables, and that might lead you to have a good conversation on another topic. If they say "yes, now go code one up" then you just go implement a hash table. I can't see this backfiring as long as you're honest and polite the whole time.

Comment: For insert and delete, you are given the element; and for the get you are given the index, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you have mentioned is the [chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining) technique for collision resolution that is most widely used and implemented in most implementations. And as others have commented it's almost impossible to implement a HashMap with guaranteed O(1) get, insertion and deletion.

Moreover, to implement a map with just an array, you can use an [open-addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) approach to collision resolution. It is a different collision resolution technique in which no pointers are used, just an array that is larger than the maximum number of elements that would ever be stored in the map. There are several ways for implementing open addressing based collision resolution, but the simplest of them all is the linear probing technique. You can read more about it's implementation [here](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Open_addressing).